# Docker daemon memory consumption grows over time

Tags: docker, memory-leaks

Here's the scenario:

On a Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch) VM I have two containers running. The day before yesterday I got a warning from the monitoring that the memory usage is relatively high. After looking at the VM it could be determined that not the containers but Docker daemon needs them. [htop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kaXLA.png)

After a restart of the service I noticed a new increase of memory demand after two days. See graphic.

[RAM + Swap overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dyjwj.jpg)

Is there a known memory leak for this version?

[Docker version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0n4W6.jpg)

---

***Memory development (container) after 2 days:***

Container 1 is unchanged
Container 2 increased from 21.02MiB to 55MiB

---

**Memory development (VM) after 2 days:**
The MEM increased on the machine from 273M (after reboot) to 501M

dockerd
- after restart 1.3% MEM% 
- 2 days later 6.0% of MEM%

Comment: We are seeing exactly the same issue, did you ever find a fix?

Answer (score 1):

Monitor your containers to see if their memory usage changes over time:

`> docker stats`

```
CONTAINER ID        NAME                CPU %               MEM USAGE / LIMIT     MEM %               NET I/O             BLOCK I/O           PIDS
623104d00e43        hq                  0.09%               81.16MiB / 15.55GiB   0.51%               6.05kB / 0B         25.5MB / 90.1kB     3
```

Comment: I have added the data to the description :-)

Comment: @SarahSchwab: Any break through?? We are currently facing the same issue with 

docker version
Client:
 Version:           19.03.6

Answer (score 1):

We saw a similar issue and it seems to have been related to the `gcplogs` logging driver. We saw the problem on docker 19.03.6 and 19.03.9 (the most up-to-date that we can easily use).

Switching back to using a log forwarding container (e.g. logspout) resolved the issue for us.